# Accessing historical precipitation data outside of GEE

Tags: data, remote-sensing, api, precipitation, nasa

I'm looking for historical and also present climate data for some polygons I have.
I would like to be able to **access rainfall data for these points. I cannot use GEE and was struggling to find a good source for this data.**

I have tried to find API of [NASA](https://api.nasa.gov/) /[Giovanni](https://giovanni.gsfc.nasa.gov/giovanni/) (or [this](https://data.nasa.gov/Earth-Science/Giovanni/3hkq-hqyc/data))  but seems like they don't have climate data available with API.

My question is if anyone has any **recommendation for a good source** of historical rainfall data, so I can get the precipitation value for specific days.

Comment: I agree with @user2856 that a better place for  open data recommendations is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange where such questions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look into the **[WorldClim](https://www.worldclim.org) project**?
They provide gridded data on past weather, climate, bioclimatic variables, not just of the past but also on the future climate based on several global climte models.
The ceveate may be the resolution of 2.5 minutes for the historic weather data (which is pretty good for a global data set, but may not be sufficient for your needs).

**Historical monthly weather data** (1960-2018; 2.5 minutes resolution) [here](https://www.worldclim.org/data/monthlywth.html)
[image]

**Historical climate data** (1970-2000) [here](https://www.worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html)
[image]

**###################** **UPDATE 2022-01-26** **###################**

I just stumbled on [this paper by **E. Kusch & R Davy (2022)**](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-9326/ac48b3). Their R-Package is rather usefull by itselfe, but they also provide a good overview over other data-sets that may be usefull here:

[image]